# Get the threads which contain a certain .NET function in their call stack?

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, sosex

I have a user mode dump with 73 threads. Some of them are managed and some of them native.
I would like to find the managed thread, which call stack contains a certain managed function.

I have the *SOSEX* extension loaded in the debugger.

Right now I do `~*e !mk` to dump all the managed threads and then browse through them manually looking for what I need - too long and tiresome.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Related commands

There is `!findstack <module> 2` to find threads that have a specific module on the stack, but IMHO it only works well for native callstacks and for modules only, not for methods.

Then there is `!uniqstack` which might help narrowing down the threads in case many threads have the same callstack. It's also a native command.

### Ugly built-in solution

What I do in such cases is an ugly workaround, but I have not found something better yet:

```
.shell -ci "!clrstack" find "Class.Method("
```

Of course you can combine this with `~*e` to do it for all threads.

```
~*e ? $tid;.shell -ci "!clrstack" find "Program.Main("
```

### PyKd script

If you don't mind installing another WinDbg extension, I recommend [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) for a more convenient and silent solution. Create a file `findstack.py` in WinDbg directory (or maybe the working directory of WinDbg, not so sure, otherwise use the full path) with the content

```
from pykd import * 
if "Class.Method(" in dbgCommand("!clrstack"):
    print(hex(expr("$tid")))
```

In WinDbg, run the script like this:

```
.load E:\path to\x86\pykd.pyd
*** Actually it's a DLL and I prefer renaming it
*** .load E:\path to\x86\pykd.dll
~*e !py findstack.py
```

Of course you can parameterize the script, e.g. like

```
from pykd import *
import sys
if (len(sys.argv) < 4):
    print "find <command> <search term> <success command>."
    quit()

if sys.argv[2] in dbgCommand(sys.argv[1]):
    print(dbgCommand(sys.argv[3]))
```

and then call it with arguments

```
~*e !py find.py "!clrstack" "Program.Main(" "? $tid"
```

Comment: Which version of the extension do you use?

Comment: I tested with 0.2.0.27 using Python 2.7.8 from Anaconda 2.1.0

Comment: ... in WinDbg 6.2.9200 with a .NET 4 x86 application. I didn't have version issues so far.

Comment: I have installed 64 bits python 2.7.10 from Anaconda and pykd-0.2.0.29-x64-python-2.7-setup.exe. And I am running the 64 bits version of WinDbg - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe". So far loading pykd.pyd immediately kills the WinDbg process :-(

Comment: @mark: indeed, the x64 versions seem broken. My WinDbg doesn't crash, but it says `The call to LoadLibrary ... failed, Win32 error 0n193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

Comment: @mark: We need the x64 version of Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/

Comment: In other words instead of Anaconda python 64 bits distro, I should use the one from python.org? Because I did install the 64 bits of python from Anaconda.