# Unexpected error with mona.py on x64

Tags: windbg, pykd

My operating system is Windows 10. I configured Mona with WinDbg according to [the documentation on the website](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2012/12/31/jingle-bofs-jingle-rops-sploiting-all-the-things-with-mona-v2).

I can use Mona with WinDbg x86. But in WinDbg x64 it says:

```
0:000> .load pykd.pyd
0:000> !py mona
unexpected error
```

Could anyone please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: For others: mona.py source is here: https://github.com/corelan/mona/blob/master/mona.py but the term "unexpected error" seems not contained in the script

Comment: Do you have Python x64 installed? Possibly the PyKd extension will load, since it's a 64 bit DLL, but once it tries to find Python to do something, it fails.

Comment: GOT IT. I didn't install Python x64 .  But after installation, windbg can't work...It will be closed  when debugging.

Comment: Hmm, you seem to have the same issue like [mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/80002/mark) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437450/get-the-threads-which-contain-a-certain-net-function-in-their-call-stack) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 2.7.11 python? It has the known bug: python can not be initialized in embedded mode on the Windows ( x86 and x64 both ). See http://www.hexblog.com/?p=949.

I recommend you use 2.7.10.

And I don't recommend you use mona.py in x64 windbg, it can not work properly nor with x64 application nor with wow64 application.